# NavigationLink(value:, label:) does not work with NavigationDestination(for:, destination:)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an issue with `NavigationStack` and `.navigationDestination`. This is a slightly simplified version of a view body in my app.

```swift
VStack {
    // other views

    List {
        Section("Recent Activity") {
            ForEach(viewModel.posts) { post in
                NavigationLink(value: post) {
                    PostListItemView(post: post)
                }
            }
        }
        
        Section("Reading List") {
            ForEach(viewModel.books) { book in
                NavigationLink(value: book) {
                    ReadingListItemView(
                        title: book.title,
                        authors: book.authors,
                        familiarity: book.familiarity
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
.navigationDestination(for: Book.self) { book in
    BookDetailsView(book: book, familiarity: .constant(book.familiarity))
}
.navigationDestination(for: Post.self) { post in
    PostDetailView(post: post)
}
```

Both `Book` and `Post` conform to `Hashable`.
Tapping on a `ReadingListItemView` results in the following error message:

> A NavigationLink is presenting a value of type “Book” but there is no matching navigationDestination declaration visible from the location of the link. The link cannot be activated.
>
> Note: Links search for destinations in any surrounding NavigationStack, then within the same column of a NavigationSplitView.

The the view is a child of a Navigation Stack. There is no other `navigationDestination(for: Book.self)` in the stack. The tapping a `PostListItemView` in the adjacent section behaves as expected. Moving the `navigationDestination` to the relevant `List` or `Section` don't improve the situation.

The only things I can think of that might be confusing the system are:

1. The parent of the view code above is itself a list item, so perhaps list virtualization is a problem somehow.
2. The root view is a `TabView` with three tabs. Each tab has its own navigation stack. An adjacent tab *does* have a `navigationDestination(for: Book.self)` in it.
3. If I replace each tab's `NavigationStack` with a single stack that wraps the whole `TabView`, navigation works *better*, but it still exhibits some strange pushing behavior where views are pushed onto the stack that weren't requested AFAICT.

I'd appreciate any insight into what I'm missing.

Comment: Not directly related but `.constant` should not be used anywhere but Previews, it is a dead end any any changes via that `familiarity` variable will be discarded.

Comment: Yep. That’s the desired behavior in this situation. The `ReadingListItemView` will never try to change it in this context.

Comment: If it will never change why have a binding and not a let variable? Binding is by definition a 2 way connection.

Comment: Because it is used differently in some circumstances. Sometimes I want the value to change. In this particular case I don’t.

This seems like it’s getting away from the question at hand.

Comment: You haven't provided and Minimal Reproducible Example, there is no way to help you with your actual question

Comment: Each `TabView` should have its own `NavigationStack`. Did you try making `.navigationDestination` a modifier of the `List`?

Comment: > Moving the navigationDestination to the relevant List or Section don't improve the situation.

Yes. It doesn’t improve things.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a functional MRE and it does work like expected. So the issue might be somewhere else in code you don't show.

```
struct Post: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    var message: String
}

struct Book: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title: String
}

let viewModelposts = [
    Post(message: "Message One"),
    Post(message: "Message Two"),
    Post(message: "Message Three")
]

let viewModelbooks = [
    Book(title: "Book One"),
    Book(title: "Book Two"),
    Book(title: "Book Three")
]


struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ChildView()
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // other views
            List {
                Section("Recent Activity") {
                    ForEach(viewModelposts) { post in
                        NavigationLink(value: post) {
                            //PostListItemView(post: post)
                            Text(post.message)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Section("Reading List") {
                    ForEach(viewModelbooks) { book in
                        NavigationLink(value: book) {
                            //ReadingListItemView(title: book.title, authors: book.authors, familiarity: book.familiarity)
                            Text(book.title)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Book.self) { book in
            //BookDetailsView(book: book, familiarity: .constant(book.familiarity))
            Text("This is details for book: \(book.title)")
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Post.self) { post in
            //PostDetailView(post: post)
            Text("This is details for Post: \(post.message)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't an MRE if it doesn't reproduce the problem. I've attempted to reproduce in a simpler context, but it usually works as advertised. I didn't show it in the code snippet, but I tried to describe some of the complicating factors which seem suspicious in the description below the snippet.

> So the issue might be somewhere else in code you don't show.

I suspect the same. I'm hoping that someone might have some insight into what might cause this behavior. It is a non-trivial codebase that I can't share publicly, but I'll keep trying to find an MRE.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was ultimately that there were too many `navigationDestination(for: Hashable, destination:)` modifiers in the navigation stack in some circumstances. The problem was They would occasionally conflict with one another, resulting in strange error messages like:

> Update NavigationRequestObserver tried to update multiple times per frame.

My ultimate solution was to move most of the `navigationDestination` modifiers nearer the root of the navigation stack, which made some of the more convoluted parts of my navigation hierarchy more obvious.

It did not solve the problem completely, but it did reduce the amount of surprising navigation behavior I was seeing.